# Javascript game framework or library for board games?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to build a card game in Javascript.  Currently I am using Raphael to draw my graphics, but I'm bad at math, like really bad.  I'm wondering if there is a library or framework out there that would allow me to build a card game in Javascript without having to manually figure out the x and y coordinates of every object I want to draw.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that even with a library, you're still going to have to manually figure out the x/y coordinates of objects.  The only way to avoid that is to use a drag/drop game creation engine (as far as I know, no such thing exists in Javascript).

Comment: Take a look at [fabric.js](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/demos/kitchensink/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into a Javascript Game Engine, depending on your exact requirements you should find one for you.

Usually a game engine include facilities to manage sprites, layers, and scene; handle events; easy animations; redrawing regions, detecting collisions, etc.

[Render Engine](https://github.com/bfattori/TheRenderEngine) is an open source game engine that seems pretty good.
Many more are available under a commercial license.

A list of both open source and commercial game engines is available [here](https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Game-Engines), with brief descriptions to allow you to quickly find your way (discarding the not-yet-mature engines and choosing based on features or focus).